# Trying to create Embed Command discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, embed

I am creating Embed cmd for my bot and I want my bot to ask for the channel in which the user wants to send the embed, but I ran into a error while doing so.

Code:

```
@bot.command()
async def buildembed(ctx):
    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel

    await ctx.send('Waiting for a title')
    title = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
  
    await ctx.send('Waiting for a description')
    desc = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
    
    await ctx.send('Channel ID')
    guild = bot.get_guild(12345678)
    channel = guild.get_channel(await bot.wait_for('message', check=check))
    
    embed = discord.Embed(title=title.content, description=desc.content, color=discord.Color.blue())
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

> ```
> raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
> ```
>
> exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Your help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
channel = guild.get_channel(await bot.wait_for('message', check=check))
await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

`channel` is `None`, hence the error `exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member_count#discord.Guild.get_channel

`get_channel()` expects an int. You are passing a `message` object to it. You need to get the content of the message and then convert it to an int. Something like

```
int((await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)).content)
```

Really ugly code. You should refactor it to make it look more pretty. But that should work assuming the channel id that is provided is a valid channel id.

Comment: Thank You, So much and also will look into what you said

Comment: @IDK Note that `get_channel()` could still return `None` if the channel is not found. You could consider using [`TextChannelConverter.convert`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.TextChannelConverter.convert), which besides IDs also works with channel names and mentions.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the id (Message Content) but the message object in **guild.get_channel()**

```
   channel_id = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
   channel = guild.get_channel(int(channel_id.content))
```